# Trouble writing to same log file from multiple classes

Tags: c++, file, logging, ofstream

lets say I define 
class A a
and in main I declare a log object

logClass logObj
and open the logfile with
logObj.openFile(path);

Now I want to write to the log file inside class a.

So I define logObj as a member of a class and write in main

a.logObj = logObj;

In order to do that I need to overload logObjs = operator.  So I do

```
logClass logClass::operator+(logClass& log)
{
    dir = log.dir;
    logFile = log.logFile;
}
```

I get an error with logFile = log.logFile.
logFile is defined as
ofstream logFile;
I need logFile in order to write to the same log file as was declared in main.  Apparently copying ofstreams is not allowed.  So how do I write to the same file.

Comment: Typo? `operator+` is not the same as `operator=`

Comment: This is a case where you probably want to use a pointer to the log object. Having two multiple copies of a log object is not very helpful. This may bv a good place for a `std::shared_ptr`, but if you define the logger in `main`, you may be able to get away with a raw pointer since the logger's not going out of scope before `main` exits and if you still have stuff live when `main` exits... well, it's in for a nasty shock. A logger is a great example of cross-cutting behaviour.  You might just want a function that logs and contains a logger instance as a `static` local variable.

Comment: And if it a typo, operator= should return a reference.

Comment: Also consider not keeping the log file open between writes to the log file. This allows you to delete and move logfiles much more easily.

Comment: @NeilButterworth good point. Plus it should keep the promise made by the signature and return a value.